# Even though JRE 8 is installed on my MAC OS Yosemite, the error - " No Java Runtime present,requesting to install "

Tags: java

Even though JRE 8 is installed on my MAC OS Yosemite 10.10.3,while running the Android present in tools in sdk - the error - " No Java Runtime present,requesting to install " gets displayed in terminal- how do i solve this issue?

I wanted to install Xamarin test recorder - after installing they asked me to install Android sdk
SDK is downloaded in Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk
Now when I run Android present in tools folder - I get the error - No Java run time
I've installed JRE 8 with get the verified java version from their site
Can someone please help!!

Answer (score 9):

You must install the full JDK, not just the JRE, to get Java support on macOS. For some reason the JRE just installs the browser plugins, not the full Java.

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) is the current JDK download page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the full JDK. I had the same issue and eventually solved it by placing the following JAVA_HOME export in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Hope this helps someone. I'm running Mac OS High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on macOS high sierra. Did not install JDK.

Go to terminal:

1. `vim ~/.bash_profile`
2. add `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`
3. Save and close it.
4. `. ~/.bash_profile`
5. `java -version`

You should be able to see java version